# Java and Oscilloscope

Tags: java, protocols, communication, lan, oscilloscope

I need to access data from an oscilloscope (Tektronix DO4034B) connected to my LAN. The oscilloscope has a web-GUI to perform the functions.

My doubt is how I develop a software in Java to perform these same functions in my program, accessing  the oscilloscope in the network.

Thanks.

Comment: Look for official API/SDK. In worst case sniff what web-gui sends/receives.

Comment: You'll have to figure out of your oscilliscope exposes an API that your Java web app can access in the same manner that the built in GUI does.

Answer (score 1):

If the oscilloscope publishes a Java API, it will be easy.  Download the API and use according to directions.

If the oscilloscope publishes a non-Java API, then it's a matter of binding the Java language to the published API.

If the oscilloscope doesn't publish an API, then you have to make a choice.

1. Figure out how to set up a service on the oscilloscope, which binds to the internal api, and presents what you desire.
2. Use a Java web client, Apache's HttpClient comes to mind, and have Java drive a program driven headless web browser.

I'd opt for #2 unless there is some overriding reason to make it integrate with a larger environment better.